# three.js: debugging hidden not appearing mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

The following code is a working example using custom geometry to draw a tetrahedron with `three.js` (relevant is `mesh2`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
<script src="three.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</header>
<body>

<script>
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh1, mesh2;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 100, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 300 );
    camera.position.z = 50;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

    // 1
    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10 );
    mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh1 );

    // 2 begin
    geometry = new THREE.Geometry( );
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 6,6, 6),  new THREE.Vector3( 10,6, 6),  new THREE.Vector3( 6,10, 6),  new THREE.Vector3( 6,6, 10) );
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0,2,1),new THREE.Face3( 1,2,3),new THREE.Face3( 1,3,0),new THREE.Face3( 0,3,2));          
    geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh2 );
    // 2 end

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    mesh1.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh1.rotation.y += 0.02;
    mesh2.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh2.rotation.y += 0.02;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

The following code tries to draw a component of a furniture:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
<script src="three.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</header>
<body>

<script>
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 100, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0, 550 );
    camera.position.z = 4000;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.add(camera);

    function cos(x) {
        return Math.cos(Math.PI*x/180);
    }
    function sin(x) {
        return Math.sin(Math.PI*x/180);
    }

    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

    var step_deg = 10;
    var count = -1;
    for(deg=0 ;deg<=360;deg+=step_deg) {
        var x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2;
        if (deg>=0 && deg<=90) {
            x1 = 400+100*cos(deg); y1 = 900+100*sin(deg); z1=0;
            x2 = x1; y2 = y1; z2 = 27;
            geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( x1,y1, z1),  new THREE.Vector3( x2,y2,z2) );
            count++; console.log(""+count+": ["+x1+","+y1+","+z1+"]");
            count++; console.log(""+count+": ["+x2+","+y2+","+z2+"]");
        } 
        if (deg>=90 && deg<=180) {
            x1 = 50+50*cos(deg); y1 = 950+50*sin(deg); z1 = 0;
            x2 = x1; y2 = y1; z2 = 27;
            geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( x1,y1, z1),  new THREE.Vector3( x2,y2,z2) );
            count++; console.log(""+count+": ["+x1+","+y1+","+z1+"]");
            count++; console.log(""+count+": ["+x2+","+y2+","+z2+"]");
        } 
        if (deg>=180 && deg<=270) {
            x1 = 50+50*cos(deg); y1 = -950+50*sin(deg); z1 = 0;
            x2 = x1; y2 = y1; z2 = 27;
            geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( x1,y1, z1),  new THREE.Vector3( x2,y2,z2) ); 
            count++; console.log(""+count+": ["+x1+","+y1+","+z1+"]");
            count++; console.log(""+count+": ["+x2+","+y2+","+z2+"]");
        } 
        if (deg>=270 && deg<=360) {
            x1 = 400+100*cos(deg); y1 = -900+100*sin(deg); z1 = 0;
            x2 = x1; y2 = y1; z2 = 27;
            geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( x1,y1, z1),  new THREE.Vector3( x2,y2,z2) ); 
            count++; console.log(""+count+": ["+x1+","+y1+","+z1+"]");
            count++; console.log(""+count+": ["+x2+","+y2+","+z2+"]");
        }       
    }
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 400,900, 0),  new THREE.Vector3( 400,900, 27) ); // 80, 81
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 50,950, 0),  new THREE.Vector3( 50,950, 27) );   
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 50,-950, 0),  new THREE.Vector3( 50,-950, 27) ); 
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 400,-900, 0),  new THREE.Vector3( 400,-900, 27) );   // 86, 87
    for(i=0;i<40;i++) {
        geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( i*2, (i*2+2) % 80, i*2+1) );  
        console.log("["+i*2+","+ ((i*2+2) % 80)+","+ (i*2+1)+"]");
        geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( i*2+1, (i*2+2) % 80, (i*2+3) % 80) ); 
        console.log("["+(i*2+1)+","+ ((i*2+2)%80)+","+ ((i*2+3) % 80)+"]");
    }
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 82,20,80), new THREE.Face3( 18,80,20),
        new THREE.Face3( 84,38,82), new THREE.Face3( 84,40,38),
        new THREE.Face3( 80,86,82), new THREE.Face3( 82,86,84),
        new THREE.Face3( 0,78,80), new THREE.Face3( 80,78,86),
        new THREE.Face3( 60,84,86), new THREE.Face3( 60,58,84)
    );
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 83,81,21), new THREE.Face3( 19,21,81),
        new THREE.Face3( 85,83,39), new THREE.Face3( 85,39,41),
        new THREE.Face3( 81,83,87), new THREE.Face3( 83,85,87),
        new THREE.Face3( 1,81,79), new THREE.Face3( 81,87,79),
        new THREE.Face3( 61,87,85), new THREE.Face3( 61,85,59)
    );
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 80, 2*(i+1), 2*i),new THREE.Face3( 81, 2*i+1, 2*(i+1)+1),
            new THREE.Face3( 82, 2*(i+1)+20,2*i+20),new THREE.Face3( 83, 2*i+21, 2*(i+1)+21),
            new THREE.Face3( 84, 2*(i+1)+40,2*i+40),new THREE.Face3( 85, 2*i+41, 2*(i+1)+41),
            new THREE.Face3( 86,  (2*(i+1)+60)%80,2*i+60),new THREE.Face3( 87, 2*i+61, (2*(i+1)+61)%80)
        );
    }
    geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();

    var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromPoints( geometry.vertices );
    console.log( box.min, box.max, box.getSize() );

    material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Basically it is the same technology but more complex. This second example does not show up.

My questions:

1. Is there a rule of dumb, given that the mesh is in x=0..500,y=-1000..1000,z=0..27 (mm), how do I set `PerspectiveCamera` and `camera.position.z` (or to generalize: given x=-X..X,y=-Y..Y,z=-Z..Z)?
2. How sensible is the library from stopping rendering the object (in the console there is no error!)?

   - Can the orientation of a some faces be inverted?
   - Can the surface be incomplete?
   - What else could be wrong?

**EDIT** 
Now it works! I made following change

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 500, 0 );
camera.position.z = 3000;
```

If I understand it correctly, we are in the point (0,0,3000) observing in the direction of (0,0,0) with an angle of 60°, and the "near" is the xy-plane with z=500 resp. the "far" is the xy-plane with z=0. The mesh is 100% correct (at the first try! ;-) ).

**EDIT 2** Fiddle with the complete furniture: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kmagjfvs/10/)

Updated, now the animation make a lot more meaningful. But the main point is: I need the center of the furniture in the center of the picture. I need some sort of function "lookAt" for the camera and set it to the difference between camera position and furniture center (`pos_center.add(pos_camera.negate()).normalize()`).

The granite texture for the floor does not work, but this is another question.

Comment: Since the question has been answered by you, please submit an answer yourself and select it as correct. Helps with the tagging of questions in the SO DB. Thanks!

Comment: your camera definition is not correct (even if it works). You are specifying a near clipping plane of 500 (normal values are close to 0.1) and far clipping plane of 0 (normal values are much larger and depend on the size of your world)

Comment: a fiddle would help in the debugging

Comment: @JonathanBrooks My answer is not correct and incomplete (point 2 has not been addressed)

Comment: @gaitat Thank you for the good idea, I added a fiddle

Comment: @gaitat thank you. I've applied your hint and the rendering problem is now solved.